# Why sencond loop always run faster than the first in my case

Tags: javascript

Recently, I try to learn Javascript in deep. I try to run two loops for two different two-dimensional array ( but it's really same number value ). The second loop always run faster than first at least 2 times, maybe 10 times. In my opinion, execution time between them not too much difference. Can you help me explain this, give me any documents that talk about this. Thank you so much.

```
let a = [
  [1, 2, 22, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
  [1, 2, 22, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
];
let z = [
  [1, 2, 22, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
  [1, 2, 22, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
];

let b = 0;
let c = 0;

console.time('time1');

for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
    b += a[i][j];
  }
}
console.timeEnd('time1');  //output : time1: 0.074ms
console.time('time2');
for (let i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
    c += z[i][j];
  }
}

console.timeEnd('time2'); //output : time2: 0.013ms
```

Can you help me explain this, give me any documents that talk about this. Thank you so much.

Comment: Fractions of milliseconds mean absolutely nothing. I don't think this is worth drawing any conclusions from.

Comment: @CertainPerformance +1 Correct. this is randomly based on your machine state, you can't predict it, in my machine second function slower than first one sometimes first one slower, it doesn't even matter